# Primefaces p:ajaxStatus onerror not called

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, primefaces

I'm trying to handle a ViewExpiredException exception on an ajax call using primefaces 2.2.1 on glassfish 3.1.  I have an ajaxStatus like this:

```
  <p:ajaxStatus id="ajaxStatus"  
                onstart="startAjaxDisplay()" 
                onerror="ajaxErrorHandler()" 
                oncomplete="endAjaxDisplay()"/>
```

The onstart and oncomplete get called as expected.  I know the ajaxErrorHandler() works because I put it in oncomplete instead and it got called.  All it's doing right now is popping up an alert().  I set up my test and the response from the server looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partial-response>
  <error>
    <error-name>class javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</error-name>
    <error-message><![CDATA[viewId:/index.xhtml - View /index.xhtml could not be restored.]]></error-message>
  </error>
  <changes>
    <extension primefacesCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":false}</extension>
  </changes>
</partial-response>
```

That's all as expected except the onerror just doesn't get called.  Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

Comment: How you simulate the error? Do you excplicitly throw `ViewExpiredException` or do you only suppose it should be called on some place. I ask this because my idea is that what if you get some other error before that named error and the `ViewExpiredException` is because of that not called.

Comment: In this case, I'm getting the session from facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession() and then calling invalidate() on it.  The method that calls it is getting called from a different browser window.  I've also tried things like restarting the server and setting a really short session timeout.

Comment: My 'answer' was a question about that are you 100% sure that said invalidate() method throws exactly the said `ViewExpiredException` and nothing else? My assumption is that it may throw some else and that's why you don't see it. That's an assumption that came in mind, not a scientifically proven answer.

Comment: The invalidate doesn't throw anything.  It's the next ajax request after the session is invalidated that creates that partial response with the error.  Primefaces doesn't seem to recognize it as an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The onerror handler will be not called, because **ViewExpiredException** is not an AJAX error, but a JSF during the construction of the view that is already expired (the session expired).
PrimeFaces ajax component not handle this situation as an error.

In my solution (JSF2+PrimeFaces3) I investigate the ajax response from the server and search for an JSF error message. See the most simple example below:

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <script language="javasript" type="text/javascript">
        function handleAjaxRequest(xhr, status, args){
            var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
            errorNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('error-name');
            if (errorNodes.length == 0) return;
            errorName = errorNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            switch (errorName) {
                case 'class javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException': 
                    alert ('Session expired, redirecting to login page!');

                    window.location.href = 'login.xhtml';
                break;
            }
        }    
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="frmText">
        Enter the value: <p:inputText value="#{bean.text}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Enter" update="frmText" 
                         oncomplete="handleAjaxRequest(xhr, status, args);"/>
        <p:separator />
        The entered text is: <h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" style="font-weight: 900"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: I ended up doing essentially the same thing but using an exception handler on the back to send a redirect rather than catching it on the client side.